# getting 0 by allocating new memory for array in java

Tags: arrays

```
int myArray1[] = {1,3,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    myArray1 = new int[7];
    
    
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
        System.out.println(myArray1[i]);
    }
```

1. why i get 7 zeros when i write myArray1 = new int[7];

Comment: Because you throw away the values you assigned to it when you follow that assignment with `myArray1 = new int[7]`. Remove that line of code. Also, the first line of your code (`int myArray1[]`) contains 8 elements, not 7.

Answer (score 0):

On the second line you're overwriting your populated array with a brand new array which has no values, but you're reserving seven spots in the array for values, but you aren't providing any initial values for those spots so the compiler assigns them the default value for the array's type. In the case of an `int` the default value is `0`.

So, seven uninitialized `int` values gives you seven zeroes.

Note: if you provide a list of values when you initialize the array you don't need to provide the length.

Comment: I'd read the code again. You missed the first line.